# How do i change page template in bulk?

Tags: pages, templates, bulk

Googled for a long time, but did not find any solution. The case is - I have 950 pages I'd like to switch to other template. If i do it manually - it will take some time.
If I do it via admin panel - it takes more than 2gb of server RAM to process this request, which is not a good option for me.

Is there any script loop i can use? Or direct SQL query to run?

Comment: 950 pages are not *all* of your pages? Any route you take it seems like you'll have the problem of needing to pick something 950 times. Do you have a list of page IDs or anything?

Comment: Sure I can get page IDs of these pages. 
And yes, 950 pages are not all of my pages.

Comment: You should be able to come up with a simple SQL query to run. Take a look at the db, `postmeta` table. My quick impression is that templates are stored as meta with key `_wp_page_template`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
        $pages = get_posts();

        $page_ids_to_swap_the_template = array( 1, 2, 3, etc... );

        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            if ( in_array( $page->ID, $page_ids_to_swap_the_template ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $page->ID, '_wp_page_template', 'new_template.php' );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Nathan. It looks like the right solution. Where do i put this code? functions.php or any other php file?

Comment: Either will work. You could wrap it in a function and then just  `add_action( 'init', 'page_template_function' );`

Comment: Hey Damir, did this solution work for you? Curious if you found help, or if you need more instruction.